# How can I read scanned-PDF file in R

Tags: r, scanning

I have a dataset containing information from printed then scanned and finally they put it in pdf format. I tried it to OCR but it is not coming as I expected.

I am in a learning phase in R would you please tell me how I can read these data into R?

Here is a page with that I need to convert.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/44g7ji43it857yd/1st%201.pdf?dl=0

Comment: This isn't really a specific question that is suitable for Stackoverflow, but maybe you could have a read of this: http://electricarchaeology.ca/2014/07/15/doing-ocr-within-r/

Comment: The link https://www.dropbox.com/s/44g7ji43it857yd/1st%201.pdf?dl=0 is not valid anymore